# Showing roads that are below 10 ft elevations using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, elevation

I have point elevation data and road layers for a region.

How do I show the road sections that are below 10 ft elevations?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your point data to raster data, then to contour lines. Extract both the 10' and the lowest elevation (possibly 0') lines, convert them to polygons and clip your roads using that polygon.

Or, as @Spacedman pointed out, use Kriging and polygonize instead of contour lines.

Comment: Better to convert point to raster (kriging, or IDW), then threshold on <=10 ft, then polygonise, then clip. Not convinced a contour line algorithm will give you polygons if the line ends at the boundary...

Comment: I converted the points to raster through idw but how to set the threshold on <=10 ft? The IDW shows the minimum value of -4.77 and max of 348.35.

Comment: @Spacedman: Will you provide me some details for your method, please?

Comment: @BPS in QGIS, use the Raster Calculator to create a raster that is 1 where the DEM is < 10 and 0 elsewhere. Then I run the "polygonize" algorithm and that creates polygons. I can then intersect these with the lines. Equivalent ArcGIT operations must be there somewhere...

Comment: @Spacedman: I am using ArcGIS and not confident with QGIS. My objective is the show the roads that are equal to/below 10 ft so that i can show whether these roads will be affected by sea level rise in future. I have DEM data and also i have contour line data (2ft, 10ft, and so on) for my study region.

Comment: Since I have the contour lines for 10 ft, I used the method of @Erik and I am able to see the roads that are within the polygon of 1oft  contours. But I am not confident whether this meets my criteria of 10 ft and below?

Comment: If you are confident in ArcGIS then you can probably find its raster calculator and create a raster thresholded at 10-feet. The you can find its raster-polygon conversion and get polygons that are above and below 10 feet. Then you can use its polygon-line overlay function and get the roads below 10 feet.